# How to set text-align for all elements inside div except img?

Tags: html, css

I have a div block like this:

```
<div class="first-color-block">
  <img src="test.png"/>
        Learn More
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.first-color-block :not(img){
  text-align: right;
}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

This is what I would like the end result to look like

```
------------------------|
                        |
 *img*             text |
                        |
------------------------|
```

Comment: why not target `.first-color-block p{}`

Comment: it is a simple text without nesting in tags

Comment: Not really sure how do you want this to look. Maybe you can elaborate your explanation or add a drawing?

Comment: I added a schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding to other solutions you can make use of `flexbox`. You can `justify every item to flex-end` and having the `margin-right:auto on the img` it shifts to left.

```css
.first-color-block{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  align-items:center;
  border:2px dashed black;
  padding:10px;
}
.first-color-block img{
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-color-block">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" /> Learn More and play more
  <p>This is another text </p>

</div>
```

Comment: but the text is not aligned to the right, try to add more content. It's left aligned

Comment: @TemaniAfif justify-content:flex-end; aligns it to the right side. Aligning is the done respect to the container, and since its making use of flex the way to align it horizontally is to use justify-content.

Comment: yes but i mean the text :) take the answer of itay and add more text then add more text to yours then compare and you will get me ;)

Comment: @highdef, just add `text-align: right` to `.first-color-block`. Then it'll work.

Comment: even more :) make it two lines. and no need to add `p` tag

Comment: @ex1t3 No problem

Comment: @TemaniAfif Guess, this is what the OP needed  and adding more text does nothing but reduces the gap between the two which can be maintained by adding margin to the image. Since, it is a flexbox the image and text will never overlap.

Comment: i don't mind ;) i simply want to show you what i meant : check this : https://jsfiddle.net/p9q8av6c/

Comment: your solution is fine for the OP but i want to tell you that text is **left** aligned and not **right** aligned as you can see in the jsfiddle

Comment: @TemaniAfif https://jsfiddle.net/p8u1vdgj/ ;) And if you notice how the text messes up when text-aligned another disadvantage (If its a single line it doesnt make a difference but for multiple lines you can notice it as well). The OP probably wantedthem floated to left and right and not mess up their structure.

Comment: i know the disadvantges of floating and also of flex :) but this was not my intention, i simply want to hightlight this small thing that we cannot notice when text is not long ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know that's why I said to add to another solution this was one way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can float the `img` to the direction you want:

```css
.first-color-block {
    text-align: right;
}

.first-color-block img {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-color-block">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/32x32" /> Learn More
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L9Lux40e/).

Comment: align right to be more correct (am the upvoter not the downvoter !)

Comment: How do I put those two elements in one line?

Comment: @ex1t3 what do you mean by one line?